# How can I validates_uniqueness_of :attachment_file_name using client_side_validations/formtastic/paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, formtastic, client-side-validation

I'm using paperclip for an attachment on an instance of my model. I would like to validate the uniqueness of that attachment file name when it is uploaded by the user into the system at the client. Currently, I am implementing Paperclip's attachment_fingerprint field that holds an MD5 checksum to verify the attachment's uniqueness and `validates_uniqueness_of :attachment_fingerprint` in the model, but I would like the error message generated by it to appear at the client.

To do client side validations, I'm using the client_side_validations gem, but it looks like the only validation they support is `validates_presence_of :attachment` (See [here](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/wiki/Paperclip)).

Does anyone have any experience trying to validate the uniqueness of an attachment file name at the client and can point me in the right direction?